# Using THREE.js to make a shining sun

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm learning THREE.js to do my final project which is a simple solar system model

the only thing I don't know how to implement is how to make the sun **shining** or **twinkle**, just like the sun in [chrome experiments 100,000 stars](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/stars/),

what I want is a sun like the this:
[image]

However, below is the best I can get, which is not satisfying enough:
[image]

Hope someone could tell me what library or technique that I can use to make the sun really shining!

Thanks a lot!
Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: Maybe three.js/examples/webgl_lensflares.html will help you.

Comment: Yea I tried lensflares, but the flare just disappear when I move my camera closer to the sun, if I can make the lens flare surround the sun's surface that will be awesome, but I don't know how..

Comment: Or use a shadermaterial and for instance take this shader: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dXGR4

Comment: You make function it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sun in the 100,000 Stars Chrome experiment is mostly made up of layered images. For instance, here's the image called sun_halo.png:

[image]

You can see the code used to make that sun, including all the shaders and links to all of the images, in this file:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130325132356/http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/stars/js/sun.js

Comment: Is still available to see? Link no longer working, thanks.

Comment: Looks like a short-lived Google project, I've updated the link to a archive.org url.